# unit test with jUnit in java soft delete method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, controller

I wanted some help to unit test a controller in java, with jUnit and using the Spring Mock MVC tool. I don't know much about unit testing.

Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id_document}/delete")
    public void deleteById (@PathVariable (value = "id_document") String documentId) {
        documentService.deleteDocument(documentId);
    }
```

** It's a soft delete

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code as starting point and add more relevant test cases as per your need.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = YourController.class)
class YourControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
void whenValidInput_thenReturns200() throws Exception {
  
   mockMvc.perform(delete("/{id_document}/delete", 10000)
        .contentType("application/json")
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

}
```

Comment: What is "1000"?